# Specifying jvm arguments in ant tasks

Tags: java, ant, jvm-arguments

I am specifying jvm arguments since i was getting out of heap space exception so just to avoid that i was specifying the below parameters in my ant target that is as shown below..

```
  <junit
   printsummary="true"
   fork="yes"
   haltonfailure="false"
   failureproperty="junitsFailed"
   errorProperty="junitsFailed"
  >
   <jvmarg value=" -Xmx1024m -Duser.timezone=GMT0"/>
  </junit>
```

but below i am getting the below exception ..

```
that is the invalid parameters are specified
```

Answer (score 9):

Use multiple `<jvmarg>` elements:

```
<junit printsummary="true" fork="yes" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="junitsFailed" errorProperty="junitsFailed">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m"/>
    <jvmarg value="-Duser.timezone=GMT0"/>
</junit>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set ANT_OPTS parameters. For example in Windows

```
SET ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

or just use `maxmemory` attribute of `junit` ant task (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

```
<junit maxmemory="1024m" ...
```