# Difference between ANT task maxmemory and setting heap size via jvmarg?

Tags: jenkins, junit, ant

I am getting heap exceptions during testing:

```
[junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have read about [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039864/specifying-jvm-arguments-in-ant-tasks) solutions to this problem, but I am confused as to which is the actual correct method. In the ANT task, there is the option e.g.:

```
<junit fork="true" haltonfailure="no" maxmemory="1024m">
```

And others have recommended passing arguments via ANT_OPTS or via the task e.g.:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M">
```

Would it be redundant to set both of these values? If not, which is the recommended method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these approaches achieve the same end result, namely; your test(s) are run in a forked JVM and that JVM is run with a maximum heap size of 1024mb.

I think the considerations to bear in mind when chosing between these approaches are:

- Will the reader/maintainer of your build script be familiar with the 'raw' instruction for JVM max heap (i.e. `-Xmx`)?
- Will your `<junit>` task need multiple custom JVM args?

If the answer to both of these questions is "yes" then you have (a) a need for JVM args beyond those supported via shortcuts (such as `maxmemory`) and (b) you can expect that anyone reading/maintaining your build script will be comfortable with seeing 'raw' JVM args expressed in the build script. This would suggest that `<jvmarg>` could be used for all JVM arguments.

If the answer to these is "no" then you won't need to use `<jvmarg>` at all and you can stick with its friendly shortcut: `maxmemory`.

To put it another way, the following two declarations are functionally identical and the first one is, perhaps, simpler:

```
<junit fork="true" haltonfailure="no" maxmemory="1024m">
    ...
</junit>


<junit fork="true" haltonfailure="no">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m">
    ...
</junit>
```

By contrast, these next two declarations are also functionally identical but the second one is, perhaps, more consistent in the sense that **all** JVM args are expressed in the same way:

```
<junit fork="true" haltonfailure="no" maxmemory="1024m">
    <jvmarg value="-Denv=dev">
    ...
</junit>


<junit fork="true" haltonfailure="no">
    <jvmarg value="-Denv=dev">
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024m">
    ...
</junit>
```

However, the main point is that all of these approaches are **functionally identical** so it's really a matter of preference and, perhaps, conformance with your own project's conventions.