# Running Junit tests with mpirun using maven surefire

Tags: java, maven, junit, mpi, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to make some Junit tests using `mpirun -n 4 java <relevant arguments>`, [very similar to what was discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457336/running-unit-tests-with-mpirun-using-ant), but using maven surefire rather than ant.

From the comments in that previous question, it looks like the OP was able to achieve this by creating a dedicated script and having the `jvm` parameter of the `junit` part of his ant script reference that script.

**My question is**: does an equivalent feature exist in maven firesafe? Something that would allow me to change the "java" command used to an arbitrary script? Or should I create a specific ant script to call from maven?

Here is an exerpt of my `pom.xml` file:

```
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.22.1</version>
           <configuration>
             <!-- Specify a script with a relative path here ? -->
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little work I ended up with quite a different solution than what I was expecting.

I developed my own Junit4 runner which creates the proper `mpirun -np X java -cp...`  command for me and parses the test results of each rank.

As using a custom runner is a standard feature of Junit4, it integrates seamlessly with any environment running Junit tests, including the Maven Surefire (and Failsafe) plugins which were of particular interest for me.

I will not develop the implementation details of how this custom Junit runner works but if you are interested, I just released it on GitHub (website: https://handist.github.io/mpi-junit/).